# Good expiration time for a streaming pre-signed Amazon Cloudfront URL

Tags: html, video, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

If I am creating a streaming distribution on Cloudfront to distribute video files to a player, what length of time should I set the pre-signed URL to? On other words, can I make the URL expire in 1 minute for a 20 minute video since the streaming has already started? Or do I need to set it to be something larger than the duration of the video?

I would like to make the URL expire as soon as possible without degrading the user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it to 1 min. Afaik it just means the link is avaiable for the time it was accessed the first time, so the stream works fine if it's rmtp.